# How to execute vbs file on a remote machine

Tags: vbscript, remote-execution

How to execute a VBScript located on a remote machine where machines are on same domain without using PsExec?

I tried the following code, but no luck.

```
Sub RunCommand(strComputer, Command)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
    Err = objWMIService.Create("cmd /c " & Command, Null, Null, intProcessID)
    If Err > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error occured on Remote Server", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Runcommand("HE2264","C:\Temp\Test.vbs")    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run VBScripts with either `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`, not with CMD.

```
Err = objWMIService.Create("wscript.exe " & Command, Null, Null, intProcessID)
```

Also, you need to [remove the parentheses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) from the `RunCommand` call in `Test`:

```
Runcommand "HE2264", "C:\Temp\Test.vbs"
```

Comment: Similarly, If I want to execute a bat file can I go with wscript.exe as mentioned?

Comment: Or leave the parentheses and prefix with `Call ` *(point 3.2 in the linked article)*.

Comment: @santosh Of course not. Batch files require a different interpreter (`cmd.exe`) than VBScript files (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`).